# Operand Should contain one Column(s)

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.6 and i see there are many changes to the normal when the following should work.....

```
INSERT INTO `prabhupad`.`service`
            (`idSerInfo`,
             `NameService`,
             `HoursDone`,
             `Incharge`,
             `Comments`,
             `LPEarned`,
             `AvgRating`)
VALUES      ('1',
             'Paduka Seva',
             '20',
             'Amalatma prabhu',
             '\"Nice\"',
             '00',
             '4');
```

this query Says that the operand Should contain one column(s)

I have mysql 5.6.. Using Java Server pages... but tht does not matter since i am just asking the mysql end...

Comment: Are you sure that is definitely the failing query? Any triggers on the table? [Works fine on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08f8e/1)

Comment: The returned error is "error 1241: the operand must contain 1 column.. the link for this error is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html

Comment: all google hits are for subqueries.. either a trigger or you didn't tell us the actual query you're running.

Comment: Yep, this is the wrong query.

Comment: Yes there is a trigger but ... this is not the error code which comes... I had a time when the reply was from a trigger.... saying the triggger deleted...  Ok I will do one thing.. I will delete the triggers and see

Comment: Thanks to you guys.. you are terrific.

Yes it works... I deleted the trigger...